# How to use custom Router in Akka 2.3?

Tags: scala, akka

Update: The source code for the whole [akka project is now available here](https://bitbucket.org/drozdyuk/airplane-akka), with this problem filed as an [issue](https://bitbucket.org/drozdyuk/airplane-akka/issue/1/rewrite-custom-router-in-current-akka).

I am having trouble rewriting an example of a custom router from [Akka Concurrency](http://www.artima.com/shop/akka_concurrency) book (section 10.6). Here is the piece of code in question:

```
package zzz.akka.avionics

import akka.actor.{Props, SupervisorStrategy}
import akka.dispatch.Dispatchers
import akka.routing.{RouterConfig, RouteeProvider, Route, Destination}

class SectionSpecificAttendantRouter extends RouterConfig {
  this: FlightAttendantProvider =>

  // The RouterConfig requires us to fill out these two
  // fields. We know what the supervisorStrategy is but we're
  // only slightly aware of the Dispatcher, which will be
  // discussed in detail later
  def routerDispatcher: String = Dispatchers.DefaultDispatcherId
  def supervisorStrategy: SupervisorStrategy =
    SupervisorStrategy.defaultStrategy

  // The createRoute method is what invokes the decision
  // making code.  We instantiate the Actors we need and then
  // create the routing code
  def createRoute(routeeProvider: RouteeProvider): Route = {
    // Create 5 flight attendants
    val attendants = (1 to 5) map { n =>
      routeeProvider.context.actorOf(Props(newFlightAttendant), "Attendant-" + n)
    }

    // Register them with the provider - This is important.
    // If you forget to do this, nobody's really going to
    // tell you about it :)
    routeeProvider.registerRoutees(attendants)

    // Now the partial function that calculates the route.
    // We are going to route based on the name of the
    // incoming sender.  Of course, you would cache this or
    // do something slicker.
    {
      case (sender, message) =>
        import Passenger.SeatAssignment
        val SeatAssignment(_, row, _) = sender.path.name
        List(Destination(sender,
             attendants(math.floor(row.toInt / 11).toInt)))
    }
  }
}
```

My questions:

1. Should I extend `Pool`, `RouterConfig` or `CustomRouterConfig`?
2. How can I get a `sender` reference in order to calculate the index from the flight attendant's path?

Here is my broken beginnings:

```
class SpecificRoutingLogic extends RoutingLogic {
  override def select(message: Any, routees: IndexedSeq[Routee]): Routee = {
    ??? no sender here!
  }
}
class SectionSpecificAttendantRouter extends CustomRouterConfig {
  this: FlightAttendantProvider =>

  override def routerDispatcher: String = Dispatchers.DefaultDispatcherId

  //override def supervisorStrategy: SupervisorStrategy = SupervisorStrategy.defaultStrategy

  override def createRouter(system: ActorSystem): Router = {
    // Create 5 flight attendants
    val attendants = (1 to 5) map { n =>
      system.actorOf(Props(newFlightAttendant()), "Attendant-" + n)
    }
    new Router(new SpecificRoutingLogic())
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Documentation does not mention about when you inherit from `CustomRouterConfig`, Akka engine does not create routees for you. Therefore nothing routes your messages. I would do that way:

```
class SpecificRoutingLogic extends RoutingLogic {
  override def select(message: Any, routees: IndexedSeq[Routee]): Routee = {
    val selected = routees.take(5)
    if(selected.isEmpty) NoRoutee
    else selected
  }
}
class SectionSpecificAttendantRouter(nrOfInstances: Int) extends Pool {
  this: FlightAttendantProvider =>

  override def routerDispatcher: String = Dispatchers.DefaultDispatcherId

  override def createRouter(system: ActorSystem): Router = {
    new Router(new SpecificRoutingLogic())
  }
}
```

I've changed `SectionSpecificAttendantRouter` extends now `Pool` not `CustomRouterConfig` due to issue I've wrote above. When you have this implementation (I think thats all) you create Router you have to do somethin like this `SectionSpecificAttendantRouter(5).props(Props[YourWorker])` - this code have to be invoked inside for example `system.actorOf()` to create concrete router. Remember, if you want to inherit directly from CustomRouterConfig you have to implement creating Routees by yourself. Take a look at class [akka.routing.RoutedActorCell](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/routing/RoutedActorCell.scala) particulary method `start()`. If you use something than Pool or Group you have to do some initialization stuff by yourself.