# How to use NoRoutee as catch-all case for custom routing logic?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, akka

I am having trouble specifying some custom routing logic for my Akka Router. Here is what I have so far:

```
class OrderRoutingLogic extends RoutingLogic {

  private val markets = mutable.Map.empty[Security, ActorRef]

  def select(message: Any, routees: IndexedSeq[Routee]): Routee = {
    message match {
      case order: Order => ActorRefRoutee(markets(order.security))
      case _            => NoRoutee  // will send to DeadLetters!
    }
  }
```

IntelliJ IDEA is telling me that I have not specified the `select(message: Any, routees: IndexedSeq[Routee]): Routee` and I do not understand why. [How to use custom Router in Akka 2.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23117126/1305344) has an answer that uses [akka.routing.NoRoutee](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/#akka.routing.NoRoutee$) (although without pattern matching). What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `routees` parameter type is not correct: it should be `immutable.IndexedSeq[Routee]` and not `IndexedSeq[Routee]`. I agree this is tricky!

Comment: Should the IndexedSeq[Routee] be immutable by default? I thought one always had to explicitly import mutable data types?

Comment: The `IndexedSeq` is in the `scala.collections` package which generally point to the immutable collection. To be honest I don't know why for `IndexedSeq` the default is the mutable one, the [scala documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/overview.html) is clear "By default, Scala always picks immutable collections.".

Comment: I was wrong, the `IndexedSeq` do points to an immutable implementation. The compilation error when we're not precising `immutable` is: `[error] (Note that scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[akka.routing.Routee] does not match IndexedSeq[akka.routing.Routee]: trait IndexedSeq in package immutable is a subclass of trait IndexedSeq in package collection, but method parameter types must match exactly.)
`. From what I understand, the compiler wants the _exact_ trait declared in the method (the one in `immutable`), and by writing only `IndexedSeq` we give the trait in the `collection` package.